# How to pass multiple drop table statements to for loop in dbt?

Tags: cloud, jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I want to drop multiple tables in Snowflake. Instead of adding multiple commands to my dbt job and just pass the tables names, I used the TABLES view under the INFORMATION_SCHEMA of my database and found a way to construct my drop statements from there.

Here's the statement I used to construct my drop statements:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.', TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME), '"'))
FROM "{{ var('db_name') }}"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLES"
WHERE table_owner = '{{ var("table_owner") }}'
AND table_schema = '{{ var("schema_name") }}'
AND table_name LIKE '{{ var("table_name") }}'
```

My first approach ([Which I posted a question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543594/how-to-pass-variable-to-post-hook-in-dbt)) was to put the result of the above statement to a single string and pass it to a variable then pass that variable to my post_hook. But apparently, post_hook only accepts string values. See this [post.](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/how-to-use-variables-in-config-block/3393/3)

My next approach was instead of putting the result to a single string, I'll pass the result list to a for loop with run_query command inside.

Here's my whole code:

```
{%- set generate_drop_table_statement -%}
SELECT
    CONCAT('"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('.', TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME), '"'))
FROM "{{ var('db_name') }}"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLES"
WHERE table_owner = '{{ var("table_owner") }}'
AND table_schema = '{{ var("schema_name") }}'
AND table_name LIKE '{{ var("table_name") }}'
{%- endset -%}

{%- set get_drop_statements = run_query(generate_drop_table_statement) -%}

{%- if execute -%}
{%- set drop_statements = get_drop_statements.columns[0].values() -%}

{%- set exec_query -%}
    {{ log(drop_statements, info=True) }}
    
    {% for drop_statement in drop_statements %}
        {{ log(drop_statement, info=True) }}
        {%- do run_query(drop_statement) -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endset -%}

{%- else -%}
{%- set drop_statements = [] -%}
{%- endif -%}

{{ config (
alias='DROP_STATEMENTS_TABLE',
materialized='table',
post_hook='{{ exec_query }}'
) }}

with statements as (
SELECT
    1 as id
)

SELECT *
FROM statements
```

I can see from the log that the query has been passed because of this line: `{{ log(drop_statement, info=True) }}` but after displaying the first statement, it failed to the run_query part.

This is the error that I encountered:

```
Tried to run an empty query on model 'model.learn_dbt.drop_table'. If you are conditionally running
sql, eg. in a model hook, make sure your `else` clause contains valid sql!

Provided SQL:
/* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.1.0", "profile_name": "eric-snowflake-dbt", "target_name": "dev", "node_id": "model.learn_dbt.drop_table"} */

"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ANALYTICS.DBT.TEST_X_TABLE"
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks, in advance.

**UPDATE**

I just updated my statement to this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', CONCAT_WS('.', TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME))
FROM "{{ var('db_name') }}"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLES"
WHERE table_owner = '{{ var("table_owner") }}'
AND table_schema = '{{ var("schema_name") }}'
AND table_name LIKE '{{ var("table_name") }}'
```

I noticed in the examples I found that statements passed to run_query was enclosed in *single quotes*, **not** double quotes. That fixed my problem.

Hope this will someone in future who are just starting to learn dbt.